# Error on transferring photos from iPhone onto Photos on Mac

Tags: high-sierra, photos, photos.app, data-transfer

From time to time I would like to be able to save WhatsApp photos (on my iPhone) into Photos (on my Mac).

Here is how I proceed:

1. On my iPhone I allowed WhatsApp to access my Photos (read and write).
2. From `WhatsApp` within a chat I select a photo, and open the bottom left menu to save it:

   [image: save on iPhone].
3. I connect my iPhone on my Mac, using my USB cable.
4. On my Mac I start `Photos`, select my iPhone, select the photo to import, and click `Import 1 Selected`.

And I get the following error from `Photos`:
[image: Photos error message]

NB: there is no Cloud service involved here.

---

My question is simple:

What is the real meaning and cause of this error message?

Did I do something wrong?

Is this is a known bug?

Comment: Do you have some reason requiring you to do it this way, or do you just want to get the photo onto the mac? Your question is ambiguous in what you're really trying to achieve.

Comment: Good question. What I want to do is in the title. I just tried this exposed method because I thought it should be working.

Answer (score 1):

### False error

Yes, my method is correct. The problem isn't coming from `WhatsApp` and is more general to the process of transfering photos from `Photos` on iPhone toward `Photos` on Mac.

Here is the way I was able to get back my photo on My Mac, verify it was correctly transferred, and finally import it manually inside `Photos`.

On my Mac I made a search for any file with the name produced in the error window,
from `Terminal` I entered:

```
cd ~/Pictures/Photos\ Library.photoslibrary
find . -name "6c65168d-*"
./Masters/2018/11/05/20181105-103812/6c65168d-da6c-4df4-8239-28ab4d59c9dd.JPG
./Masters/2018/11/05/20181105-103830/6c65168d-da6c-4df4-8239-28ab4d59c9dd.JPG
./Masters/2018/11/05/20181105-111753/6c65168d-da6c-4df4-8239-28ab4d59c9dd.JPG
```

The `"6c65168d-*"` argument to `find` means find any file which name begins with `6c65168d-` and print it.
The 3 result lines I got are correct and due to the fact I tried with smaller set of images 3 times to focus on the image causing the error.

Next, if I try to open any of these files, they do without any error within `Preview`, and moreover they can be easily imported within `Photos` without any error.

### Conclusion

The error message is inappropriate and seems like an internal error within `Photos` on Mac or within the transfer process from iPhone to Mac.

I will continue the analysis of this stupid bug and report it to Apple.

Errors are already enough of a problem.

False errors are worse.